# Sabre OTA_HotelResRS GUARANTEE NOT ACCEPTED

Tags: sabre

It says guarantee not accepted but I am passing a credit card and guarantee type that was specified in the HotelPropertyDescriptionRS. This failure is occurring across multiple hotels at the moment. Due to the sheer size and number of requests needed to work with Sabre, I posted the full RQ/RS trail from session creation to error on pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/NgH1LmYY

The pertinent pieces are here:

RoomRate from HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ

```
           <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="D1KZZ1" IATA_ProductIdentification="20PCT OFF SAVINGS-PACIFIC" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="028" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
              <AdditionalInfo>
                 <CancelPolicy Numeric="03" Option="D" />
                 <Commission NonCommission="true">**NON-COMMISSIONABLE PRODUCT**</Commission>
                 <Text>DELUXE KING 350 SQ FT  I KING PILLOW TOP BED</Text>
                 <Text>INTERNET ACCESS 42 INCH LCD TV CABLE CHANNELS</Text>
              </AdditionalInfo>
              <Rates>
                 <Rate Amount="239.20" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="CAD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
                    <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
                       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
                          <Charges AdultRollAway="0" Crib="0" ExtraPerson="30.00" />
                       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
                    </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
                    <HotelTotalPricing Amount="281.06">
                       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
                       <TotalSurcharges Amount="0.00" />
                       <TotalTaxes Amount="41.86" />
                    </HotelTotalPricing>
                 </Rate>
              </Rates>
           </RoomRate>
```

Guarantee's from HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ

```
        <Guarantee>
           <DepositsAccepted>
              <PaymentCard Code="AX" Type="AMERICAN EXPRESS" />
              <PaymentCard Code="CA" Type="MASTERCARD" />
              <PaymentCard Code="DC" Type="DINERS CLUB CARD" />
              <PaymentCard Code="JC" Type="JCB CREDIT CARD" />
              <PaymentCard Code="VI" Type="VISA" />
           </DepositsAccepted>
           <GuaranteesAccepted>
              <PaymentCard Code="AX" Type="AMERICAN EXPRESS" />
              <PaymentCard Code="CA" Type="MASTERCARD" />
              <PaymentCard Code="DC" Type="DINERS CLUB CARD" />
              <PaymentCard Code="JC" Type="JCB CREDIT CARD" />
              <PaymentCard Code="VI" Type="VISA" />
              <Text>/GAGT             GUARANTEE TO AGENCY TIDS/IATA NUMBER</Text>
              <Text>/GDPST            DEPOSIT WILL BE SENT</Text>
              <Text>/GDPST...         IMMEDIATE DEPOSIT TYPE OR FORM</Text>
           </GuaranteesAccepted>
        </Guarantee>
```

OTA_HotelResRQ:

```
  <OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ReturnHostCommand="true" TimeStamp="2015-05-12T02:00:26-06:00" Version="2.1.0">
     <Hotel>
        <BasicPropertyInfo InsertAfter="0" RPH="028" />
        <Guarantee Type="GDPST">
           <CC_Info>
              <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="REDACTED" Number="****REDACTED" />
              <PersonName>
                 <Surname>REDACTED</Surname>
              </PersonName>
           </CC_Info>
        </Guarantee>
        <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" />
     </Hotel>
  </OTA_HotelResRQ>
```

OTA_HotelREsRS:

```
  <OTA_HotelResRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.1.0">
     <ApplicationResults status="Complete">
        <Success timeStamp="2018-01-18T19:26:55-06:00">
           <SystemSpecificResults>
              <HostCommand LNIATA="222222">/0/0H1½Ú028/GDPSTVI****REDACTEDEXP REDACTED-REDACTED</HostCommand>
           </SystemSpecificResults>
        </Success>
     </ApplicationResults>
     <Hotel NumberInParty="2" NumberOfUnits="1" SegmentNumber="1" Status="UC">
        <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="PF" HotelCityCode="YVR" HotelCode="9976" HotelName="PAN PACIFIC VANCOUV" />
        <Guarantee>DPSTVIXXXXXXXXXXXXREDACTEDEXP REDACTED-REDACTED</Guarantee>
        <POS>
           <Source>
              <RequestorID>46796444</RequestorID>
           </Source>
        </POS>
        <RoomRates>
           <RoomRate>
              <AdditionalInfo>
                 <CancelPolicy Option="C03D" />
              </AdditionalInfo>
              <Rates>
                 <Rate Amount="239.20" CurrencyCode="CAD" DCS_AuxRateCode="D1KZZ1">
                    <HotelTotalPricing Amount="281.06">
                       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
                       <TotalSurcharges Amount="0.00" />
                       <TotalTaxes Amount="41.86" />
                    </HotelTotalPricing>
                 </Rate>
              </Rates>
           </RoomRate>
        </RoomRates>
        <Text>GUARANTEE NOT ACCEPTED</Text>
        <TimeSpan Duration="1" End="03-03" Start="03-02" />
     </Hotel>
  </OTA_HotelResRS>
```

Obviously IPCC and customer data have been redacted from the outputs below. The hotel says it accepts GDPST and VISA, yet it fails... Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular rate is showing that needs to be sold with G guarantee type.

> GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G"

Do you get a successful response after changing GDPST to G?

Comment: Sabre is SOOOO convoluted. So does GuaranteeSurchargeRequired take precedence over the Guarantee type list? What is my order of operations in determining which Guarantee Type to set in OTA_HotelResRQ?

Comment: P.s. You seem to be an expert on these matters from looking over other sabre questions, are you available for consulting?

Comment: Indeed, GuaranteeSurchargeRequired takes precedence. 
The list at the bottom of the response lists the possible guarantee types and credit cards that the property can generally accept.

Comment: This is working now, if possible, we'd certainly be willing to pay for some consulting on this matter. We've had issues with Sabre as our use of it has grown and an expert would help.

Comment: Web services is generally pretty good, however not always. This issue has been open since yesterday and you identified the problem within an hour. I am still waiting on them.... I will reach out to my account manager, but frankly I'd prefer you. You're active on these sabre tags and seem to know your stuff. We'll pay a good consultation rate.